# Constructor for JSP ( Query out of curiosity)

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am wondering if there is any way you can write a constructor for a JSP. As technically JSP is just another Java Class, container will be generating a constructor for it during translation.

I am wondering if there is a way you can provide constructor to container for initializing the given JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically no you can't as you mention the container generate a `Servlet` class for each JSP and it creates a no-args constructor that will be called by the container, you can create another constructor but this wont't be used by the container to create the class.

As a Jsp is translated to a servlet class you can override the `init()` and `destroy()` methods as a normal servlet class, you also have to take in mind the servlet lifecycle the container creates only one instance of the servlet class and call only once the `init` method after the object is constructed and the `destroy` method when the object will be destroyed as the container is shutdown.

As we are using a Jsp page I suggest you to use the methods defined for the [JspPage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspPage.html) interface it defines also two convenient methods that you can override in your page, jspInit and jspDestroy.

```
<%! public void jspInit() {   
    //init code 
 }  
%> 
<%! public void jspDestroy() {   
    //destroy code 
 }  
%>
```

Comment: Thanks @césar-loachamin for your comments.  What you are saying makes sense.. but I was looking for creating a constructor itself.  However.. I found one more construct which doesn't allow me to write constructor however gets executed post object construction.  If you are interested you can take a look at [code] @ PostConstruct [code] annotation.